# Can we use wildcards with "Android Emulator Plugin" on jenkins server?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, android-emulator-plugin

I am trying to install and run my apk on emulator with help of Android Emulator Plugin on Jenkins CI, but I am unable to use wildcards, since I rename my apk file with the flavour name, build number and build date. Is there a way to make things work out?

Comment: You need to give a detailed example of what you're trying to do. I *guess* you're talking about using the "Install APK" step, which does accept wildcards (e.g. `**/*flavour*.apk`), but it's unclear.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr,Yes and here is the ERROR: "Could not find APK file '/Users/jenkins/workspace/android Customer Mobile 4.0/**/*uat*.apk' to be installed
Build step 'Install Android package' marked build as failure". And this is the path I am using PATH: "**/*${environment}*.apk"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, it *seems* that the Install APK step doesn't support wildcards.

In that case you could first copy the APK to a known path (e.g. in an Execute Shell step).

e.g.

```
shopt -s globstar
cp **/app/**/*.apk app.apk
cp **/test/**/*.apk test.apk
```